# pass selected drop down value as params in rails link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a select tag which populates list of department names, When I select a value from drop down, I need to display an edit link below (link_to) and append the selected value of dropdown as id params.(I am not using form for this single select tag since I dont need to save value in my databse). How this could be possible. Please help. I am using rails2.3

I tried like the below but it didn't work.

```
  Select A Dept
    <%=select :select_dept, :dept, @dept.map{|dept| [dept.full_name, dept.id]},{:prompt => "#{t('select_a_batch')}"} %>
     <%= link_to "Display", {:controller => "user", :action => "display_value", :id => $('#select_dept').val() } ,:class => "button" %>
```

Comment: you can do one thing, on change of value of select, change the id of the link by javascript. This will be quite easy I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gopal is on the right track.

Give the link an id so you can pick it out

```
<%= link_to 'Display", {:controller ...}, :class => 'button', :id => 'display_link' %>
```

Hide it with CSS by default

```
#display_link { display:none; }
#display_link.showing { display:block; }
```

Then in javascript, do something like

```
$('#select_dept').on('change', function(ev) {
   var deptId = $(this).find(':selected').val();
   var newPath = '/users/' + deptId + '/display_value';
   $('#display_link').attr('href', newPath);
   $('#display_link').addClass('showing');
});
```

This will not set things up on page load, but you could run the same function you've passed as the `change` callback on page load to set things up (assuming one of the items might be selected on load).